# Libgdx - collisions between two moving circles

Tags: java, libgdx, geometry, collision

I've many circles randomly spawned in my screen and moving in different directions. I'm now dealing with collisions between them. The code below just compare any circle on the screen with any other one and should detect collisions by the classic formula. It more or less works, my issue is that I need to use a "magic number" discovered by tries and I can't figure out the reason.
(Every circle has the same radius)

Code:

```java
Target item1, item2;
    int magicNumber = 40;
    float dX, dY;
    for (int i = len; --i >= 0;) {
        item1 = activeTargets.get(i);
        for(int j = len; --j >= 0;){
            if(i!=j) {
                item2 = activeTargets.get(j);
                dX = (item1.getPosition().x > item2.getPosition().x) ? item1.getPosition().x - item2.getPosition().x : item2.getPosition().x - item1.getPosition().x;
                dY = (item1.getPosition().y > item2.getPosition().y) ? item1.getPosition().y - item2.getPosition().y : item2.getPosition().y - item1.getPosition().y;
                if ( (dX*dX) + (dY*dY) < (magicNumber*4*item1.body.radius*item1.body.radius) ) {
               // if(item1.body.overlaps(item2.body)) {
                    if(!activeTargets.get(i).collide && !activeTargets.get(j).collide ) {
                        activeTargets.get(i).collide = true;
                        activeTargets.get(j).collide = true;
                        Gdx.app.log("COLLIDE", "Collision between " + activeTargets.get(i).color.toString() + " and " + activeTargets.get(j).color.toString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could it be you're somehow drawing the sprites 40 times bigger than their radii?

Comment: @Giuseppe have you tried running a debugger and setting a breakpoint at the offending if statement to find out what values each number is?

Comment: You probably want `(item1.body.radius+item2.body.radius) * (item1.body.radius+item2.body.radius)`

Comment: I think you should consider using [Box2D](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/box2d#fixture-shapes). With Box2D you'll just need to create the circles, and Box2D will deal with the collisions for you.

Comment: To detect a circle-circle collision, you have to compare the squared distance `(dx*dx)+(dy*dy)` with the squared radiuses `(r1 + r2) * (r1 + r2)`. So your "magic number" and the "*4" just compensated this error somehow.

Comment: @Springrbua But if `r1 == r2` like the OP says, then `(r1 + r2) * (r1 + r2)` is the same as `4*r1*r1`. I suspect the visual scale is off.

Comment: @Tenfour04 you are right, i misread it, thought every circle has a random radius...

Comment: Then I began to use Box2D, thanks to everyone but expecially to vdlmrc for the advise!